# Как отправить пользователю сообщение спустя некоторое время?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

После определенного слова, бот выводит пользователю фото и нужно сделать так чтобы через 5секунд бот отправил текстовое  сообщение. Стоит вопрос, как это сделать? (сам делаю через телебот)

```
@bot.message_handler(chat_types=['private'], func=lambda msg: msg.text == 'Сумма n-первых членов')
def opredelenie_arifm(message: types.Message):
    photo1 = open('png/Group 28.png', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo1)
#сообщение ниже должно быть отправлено через 5 секунд(слово Привет к примеру)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет!')
```

Answer (score 0):

(Эта библиотека входит в обычные библиотеки пайтона, скачивать её не нужно) Если ты работаешь в IDE, по типу PyCharm импортируй модуль time - import time . Используй функцию time.sleep(Время в секундах, можно дробное число).

Comment: А еще лучше используем асинхронный бот, и time.sleep не будет стопорить выполнение всего кода для всех юзеров

Comment: асинхронный бот это как?

Comment: и куда вставить в мой код,не пойму,в хэндлер?